# Getting a white blank screen when running a flask static site app using docker even though it works when I run it without docker

Tags: python, docker, flask

So, I'm having problems running a docker image that's trying to run a static site made with Python Flask and HTML and when I run it, it only shows a blank screen with only one
200 HTTP GET request ("172.17.0.1 - - [23/Jan/2024 18:55:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -") and no static content loading or css loading. This is the opposite of when I run it locally, with python ./app.py; it works fine and all the content is loaded. Here is my file tree:

```
 -templates:
   -assets
   -index.html
   -p5.html
 -app.py
 -Dockerfile
 -requirements.txt
```

Here's my code for the flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='templates/assets')

@app.route("/p5")
def getP5():
    return render_template("p5.html")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)))
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

I tried to run this using `docker run -p 8888:5000 <my username>/<image-name>` and I try to go to localhost:8888 to check it out but it gives a blank screen. I've also tried to change the copy command in the Dockerfile by copying the templates folder and the folder together separately. (So, like COPY . . and then COPY ./templates ./templates). I'm out of ideas now. Can someone point me in the right direction as to why I can't get my static site to load at all when I run the docker image?

EDIT: Here's my requirements.txt:

```
click==8.1.7
Flask==2.0.2
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.4
Werkzeug==2.2.2
```

I just did pip freeze > requirements.txt and it got me this.

Comment: Please edit your post to include `requirements.txt`

Comment: I just want to ensure I understand correctly: the posted `requirements.txt` gets copied into the docker image, and is exactly the same as the `pip freeze` output. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: Yes. The requirements.txt gets copied into the image with the other files and is the same as the output of pip freeze.

Comment: Weirdly enough, this works for me. The only thing I did differently was `docker run -p 8888:5000 <image-name>` (note I didn't use `username`). This rendered some static elements that I put in index.html.

If that doesn't work, then I'm inclined to recommend tailing docker logs